# ORA-00001 / TOP001 - Pentaho Error Handling

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I'm trying to handle errors in a PDI transformation, but I'm not able to capture the 
 Oracle error :
Error inserting/updating row ORA-00001: unique constraint (string.string) violated

PDI Error_code = TOP001

PDI generated an empty reject file.

The tip that worked was uncheck the option "Use batch update for insert", but the transformation run very slow, compared as the option checked.

The flow is:
Input File >>> Output Table >>>*on error*>>> Text File Output (Error Handling)

Win10 /
Oracle 12g /
Pentaho PDI 5.4.0

Answer (score 1):

in table output you have to uncheck `use batch update for insert`

[image]

then you have to enable error handling from table output. specify the fields and then add those fields in file output steps.

Comment: Hey Jay, 
1st of all, thank you for your assistance.

I've uncheck this option but the transformation running very very slow.

Comment: is that what you looking for?

Comment: yes that's the drawback of pentaho and only that way you can get the error records. if you check that check box performance is very good.

Comment: Cool please approve the answer and like it